# QgsMapToolEmitPoint : detect mouse moving out of canvas

Tags: pyqgis

Inspired by the **RectangleMapTool** provided in Qgis documentation (https://docs.qgis.org/3.34/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/canvas.html#writing-custom-map-tools)
, I made a CircleMapTool that draws a circle when moving cursor on the canvas :
[image: Drawing circle when cursor moves]

I would like to detect mouse moves out of canvas, in order to avoid this situation (circle is "stucked" on canvas border)
[image]

Code extract:

```py
class CircleMapTool(QgsMapToolEmitPoint):
    def __init__(self, canvas):
        QgsMapToolEmitPoint.__init__(self, canvas)
        self.rubberBand = QgsRubberBand(canvas, QgsWkbTypes.PolygonGeometry)
        self.rubberBand.setColor(QColor(255, 0, 0))
        self.rubberBand.setWidth(2)

    def canvasMoveEvent(self, e):
        # out of canvas events are not raised
        point = self.toMapCoordinates(e.pos())
        self.rubberBand.movePoint(point)
```

I would like to avoid QObject.eventFilter, if possible

Comment: I prefer that the point disappears

Comment: Why don't you want to use `eventFilter`? it seems like a good way to achieve this.

Comment: Also If you provide a code sample, it needs to be a working one, or close to it, to be able to reproduce the behavior. Either the current behavior or the intended one (working or not).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this can be done without an `eventFilter` function (afaik).

If you are ok with `eventFilter` then this solution will work using a [`QEvent.HoverLeave`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qhoverevent.html) detector, built like [`QgsFocusWatcher`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsFocusWatcher.html).

[image]

```py
class QgsHoverWatcher(QObject):
    hoverEnter = pyqtSignal()
    hoverLeave = pyqtSignal()
    
    def __init__(self, parent):
        QObject.__init__(self)
        self._parent = parent
        self._parent.installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, object, event):
        if not (object is self._parent):
            return False
        elif event.type() == QEvent.HoverEnter:
            self.hoverEnter.emit()
            return True
        elif event.type() == QEvent.HoverLeave:
            self.hoverLeave.emit()
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def __del__(self):
        while True:
            try:
                self.hoverEnter.disconnect()
            except TypeError:
                break
        while True:
            try:
                self.hoverLeave.disconnect()
            except TypeError:
                break
        self._parent.removeEventFilter(self)
        
        
class CircleMapTool(QgsMapToolEmitPoint):
    def __init__(self, canvas):
        QgsMapToolEmitPoint.__init__(self, canvas)
        self.rubber_band = QgsRubberBand(canvas, QgsWkbTypes.PointGeometry)
        self.rubber_band.setColor(Qt.red)
        self.rubber_band.setWidth(20)
        
        self.canvas_hover_watcher = QgsHoverWatcher(canvas)
        self.canvas_hover_watcher.hoverLeave.connect(self.reset)

    def reset(self):
        self.rubber_band.reset(QgsWkbTypes.PointGeometry)

    def canvasMoveEvent(self, e):
        point = self.toMapCoordinates(e.pos())
        if self.rubber_band.size() == 0:
            self.rubber_band.addPoint(point)
        else:
            self.rubber_band.movePoint(point)

    def deactivate(self):
        self.reset()
        self.canvas_hover_watcher.__del__()
        QgsMapTool.deactivate(self)

tool = CircleMapTool(iface.mapCanvas())
iface.mapCanvas().setMapTool(tool)
```

PS: The reason for not using the built-in `QgsFocusWatcher` is that, with focus, you need to click somewhere outside the map canvas instead of just moving your mouse cursor.

Comment: Nice job, thank you ! Actually, I didn't want to use eventFilter because I found it quite overkill, but in the end, why not

Comment: Note : in my case, Qevent.HoverEvent/HoverLeave are not raised, I replaced them by QEvent.Enter/Leave (Qgis 3.34.1)